# In What WordPress Version Was the Import/Export Tool Introduced?

Tags: import, export

I was just looking under my "Tools" menu in my WordPress site and noticed the "Export/Import" functions.

I was not aware that this was even available and I've been needing it for some time. What version of WordPress did it originate with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exporting and Importing has been there since at least WordPress 2.1. Probably earlier. It moved into plugins with the release of 3.0, I believe.

Comment: Thanks Otto, it looks like it does not bring over the current theme. But I was super impressed that it could grab the images from the source site and transfer them to the target site!

Comment: +1 However, I also noticed it did not appear to bring over the wp_options values. Did I miss something?

Comment: No, you didn't miss anything. The Exporter and Importers handle content only. Not themes, settings, or plugins. Posts, comments, that sort of thing.